# php inserting link parts into http

Tags: php, http, getcwd

I am trying to retrieve parts of the getcwd() method and inserting them into window.open()

the current getcwd() gives me this `C:\wamp\www\qa4u\qa4u_working\Presenter`

Using this code :

```
<?php    

if(isset($_POST['genPDF'])){ 

     foreach($_POST['email'] as $email)
     {
       $eid=$_POST['eid'];
?>
             <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

                 <?
                        $stringlink = getcwd();
                        $pieces = explode('\\', $stringlink);
                 ?>                    
                    window.open("http://"+"<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>"+"/"+"<?php $pieces[3]?>"+"/"+"<?php $pieces[4]?>"+"/"+"<?php $pieces[5]?>"+"/genPDF.php?eid=<?php echo $eid ?>&email=<?php echo $email ?>");
            </script>

<?php   
     }  

}   
?>
```

I am trying to achieve this instead :

```
window.open("http://qna.nyp.edu.sg/qa4u/qa4u_working/presenter/genPDF.php?eid=<?php echo $eid ?>&email=<?php echo $email ?>");
```

without forming static links is there a way to get the code to work ?

Comment: What's the current output? Your code seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues regarding your code, that I believe prevents it from working.

1. You're not printing the pieces values. You should use `echo`, `print` or a shorthand `<?=$var ?>`
2. Since those are PHP variables, you don't need to use the JS `+` symbol

So, you should update your code:

```
window.open("http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/<?php echo $pieces[3]; ?>/<?php echo $pieces[4]; ?>/<?php echo $pieces[5]; ?>/genPDF.php?eid=<?php echo $eid; ?>&email=<?php echo $email; ?>");
```